# C# How to auto okay from RFID scanning?

Tags: c#, button, rfid

I have a program wherein the user taps an RFID card on a reader and the program will input this data. In this program, there is a prompt wherein I have to click OK. How do I remove the OK button and make it an auto-OK program once the RFID card is tapped?

Here are the parts of the program:

delegate void Function();

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sdsd = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        string Hexed = new LasalleRFIDComputerRentals.BLL.DAL.Utils().HexIt(sdsd);

        SetRFIDText(Hexed);
    }


    protected void SetRFIDText(string input)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Function(delegate()
        {
            txtRFID.Text = input;
        }));

        CustomerInfo customer = new Customer().GetCustomerByRFID(txtRFID.Text);


    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtRFID.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Please supply the RFID.", "RFID Reader", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            txtRFID.Focus();
            return;
        }

        CustomerInfo customer = new Customer().GetCustomerByRFID(txtRFID.Text);

        if (customer.CustomerID <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid RFID", "Validation");

            this.Close();
            return;
        }


        if (_parentForm == "StandBy")
        {
            Utils.CurrentCustomer.CustomerInfo = customer;

            frmStandBy form = (frmStandBy)this.Owner;

            form.xResult = "OK";
        }

        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Call btnOK_Click from inside dataReceived ought to do it? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Simply separate the logic of the OK button

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string sdsd = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    string Hexed = new LasalleRFIDComputerRentals.BLL.DAL.Utils().HexIt(sdsd);

    SetRFIDText(Hexed);
}


protected void SetRFIDText(string input)
{
    this.Invoke(new Function(delegate()
    {
        txtRFID.Text = input;
    }));

    // what is it for?
    //CustomerInfo customer = new Customer().GetCustomerByRFID(txtRFID.Text);

    SearchCustomer();

}

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchCustomer();
}

private void SearchCustomer()
{

    if (txtRFID.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Please supply the RFID.", "RFID Reader", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        txtRFID.Focus();
        return;
    }

    CustomerInfo customer = new Customer().GetCustomerByRFID(txtRFID.Text);

    if (customer.CustomerID <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid RFID", "Validation");

        this.Close();
        return;
    }


    if (_parentForm == "StandBy")
    {
        Utils.CurrentCustomer.CustomerInfo = customer;

        frmStandBy form = (frmStandBy)this.Owner;

        form.xResult = "OK";
    }

    // what is it for?
    //this.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string sdsd = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    string Hexed = new LasalleRFIDComputerRentals.BLL.DAL.Utils().HexIt(sdsd);

    SetRFIDText(Hexed);
    btnOK_click(sender, e);
}
```

This doesn't answer the question "how do I remove the OK button" since you didn't show how it was created in the first place - I suspect you need to edit the form definition for that. In that case change the code for btnOK_click from an event handler to a "regular" function (which would be a good idea anyway).

Comment: My aim is not to really remove the OK button. Maybe to hide it? But the goal is when the prompt appears, I just tap the RFID card and the prompt will automatically close. I don't have to click OK. I tried your suggestion but it said that btnOK_click does not exist in current context.

Comment: Wait, it actually kind of worked. I've tried this before. But instead, i copied the "btnOK_click" program below the SetRFIDText(Hexed);. But it seems like the program is conflicting with the This.Close(); and the Invalid RFID message box appears in the background. Why is that?

Comment: What is `This` referring to in the context of your function call? Could you refer to the form itself (by name) instead? It would avoid any confusion, and ought to work (I believe...)